Download and read an Excel file into a pandas DataFrame without saving the Excel file
I'm making a request to download an Excel file. The response is in byte form. What I usually do is save this response body as an Excel file using:
with open('filename.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.body)

and then convert it to a pandas DataFrame:
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
records = df.to_dict('records')

Is there any way to directly convert the response body into a DataFrame without saving it as an Excel file?

import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

excel_ = BytesIO(response.body)
df = pd.read_excel(excel_)
records = df.to_dict('records')

